# BCDEdit /delete {ID} Unexpected token in the ID

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bcdedit

I'm trying to remove an old linux-debian partition that I don't use anymore to increase the size of my linux-Manjaro partition.
I'm doing that on my Windows 10 by following this tutorial (in french) http://ikewdu.free.fr/desintaller-proprement-ubuntu-ou-autre-linux-en-dual-boot-uefi/

I can't delete the debian boot by using the command bcdedit /delete {identifier}

[result of bcdedit /enum firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvLXh.png)
[result of bcdedit /delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Jv3.png)

It doesn't recognize "-dfec" but it's a part of the debian identifier.
I don't know what to do and i didn't find another case like that on internet.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Use easyuefi (suggested in the tutorial as a verification step) or bcdedit to delete entries

Answer (score 0):

Hi problem partially solved.
I restart my computer and magic occured as the grub of my debian disappear.
When I do 'bcdedit /enum firmware'  the debian part don't appear so i guess it's another victory of the "Did you try to restart your PC" team.

However on the grub of my manjaro I still have the choice to go to my debian.
Is there a way to delete this option. I don't know what things can happen when trying to boot on debian if the partition is reallocted but i don't think it will be fun.
Maybe I should create another topic ?